# value is displayed even if the value is not exist in xslt1.0

Tags: html, combobox, xslt-1.0

This is my xslt code :

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string-length(
                    //Record/CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv
                    /text())
                  != 0">
    <select size="1" 
            style="width:100%;" 
            name="CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv" 
            id="CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv">
      <option>
        <xsl:attribute name="selected">true</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="//Record
                              /CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv
                              /text()" />
      </option>
     <option value="S M-SPED">S M-SPED</option>
     <option value="S M-PPPVLD">S M-PPPVLD</option>
   </select>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <select size="1" 
            style="width:100%;" 
            name="CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv" 
            id="CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv">
      <option value="0">Select Keywords</option>
      <option value="S M-SPED">S M-SPED</option>
      <option value="S M-PPPVLD">S M-PPPVLD</option>
    </select>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

but when there is no value also the when condition is there always.

I think this is the line cost problem bur not sure,

```
<xsl:when 
  test="string-length(
          //Record/CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv/text()
        ) != 0">
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show an example of input that's wrongly producing output, but I'll guess that it involves XML that might look like this:

```
<CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv>
  <!--* no value here! *-->
</CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv>
```

If you don't want whitespace in the element to count as a value, then you need to change your test from `string-length(...) != 0` to `string-length(normalize-space(...)) != 0` or the equivalent.  Because of the way XSLT coerces things to Boolean, this can be written more tersely as `normalize-space(...)` -- some proficient XSLT programmers prefer that form, while others find the implicit type coercions distracting and prefer the longer more explicit form.

If your problem is as I have conjectured, then any of the following should help:

```
<xsl:when 
  test="string-length(
          normalize-space(
            //Record/CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv/text()
          )
        ) != 0">

<xsl:when 
  test="normalize-space(
            //Record/CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv/text()
        ) != ''">

<xsl:when 
  test="normalize-space(
            //Record/CIMtrek_CI_OPEX_200910_FrDiv/text()
        )">
```

If that's not the problem, then you'll need to be more explicit about what your question is.